# how to pass hstore parameter to function using Npgsql

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

Is there a way to pass hstore input parameter to function using Npgsql.

If I had `INSERT` statement I could have used `NpgsqlDbType.Text` and appended `::hstore` to parameter name. But I couldn't find any way to pass hstore if command type is StoredProcedure.
I assume one option can be `SELECT * function_name(...)`, but even if this will work I would prefer `StoredProcedure` anyway.

**EDIT :** Adding code.

```
            var command = new NpgsqlCommand("add_info", conn);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_id", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
            command.Parameters["p_id"].Value = myId;

            command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_body", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 4096));
            command.Parameters["p_body"].Value = "Some text";

            command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_hstore", NpgsqlDbType.Text));
            command.Parameters["p_hstore"].Value = "1=>\"test1\", 2=>\"test2\"";

            result = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @CraigRinger code is added.

Comment: Hm, yeah. To do this, you'll need to see if you can configure nPgSQL to send the data-type `unknown` instead of `text` . That will permit the database to cast the field.

Comment: I have tried to set DbType.Object, but I can see it sends text anyway.